# Powershell popup message on remote system closing after defined time

Tags: powershell

I like to be able to configure in my gui how much time will elapse before closing a popup message on remote cpu. I would like to have 2 options. Popup not close and popup close after x seconds. My $seconds parameter not work.

```
Function Send-PopupMessage1 {
Param(
[Int]$Seconds=""
)


Process{
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $cpu -Scriptblock {
    $CmdMessage = "msg.exe * $using:var2 /Time:$($Seconds)"
    Write-Host $CmdMessage
    $CmdMessage | Invoke-Expression
    }
}
}

if ($checkBox1.Checked)
{
Send-PopupMessage
}
else
{
Send-PopupMessage1 -Seconds $var1
}
```

This work better. Now its good.

```
Function Send-PopupMessage1 {
Param(
[String]$Message="$var",

[Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$True,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
[Alias("Name")]
[String[]]$Computername=$var2,

[Int]$Seconds="$var1"
)


Process{
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computername -ScriptBlock{

    $cmd = "msg.exe * /Time:$($using:Seconds)"
    $cmd += " $($using:Message)"

    Invoke-Expression $cmd
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `$Seconds` => `$using:Seconds`

Comment: I dont understand - `/Time:$($using:Seconds)` ?

Comment: Yes, exactly right!

Comment: Mathias R thanx you have right now its work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `using` qualifier that make `$Seconds` available inside the `Invoke-Command` block:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $cpu -Scriptblock {
  $CmdMessage = "msg.exe * $using:var2 /Time:$($using:Seconds)"
  Write-Host $CmdMessage
  $CmdMessage | Invoke-Expression
}
```

Comment: I made a mistake in another part of the code, but without your help that did not work. Time already works just fits into the rest and i will paste solution.